# Progress DB: Set Where Value based on current date

Tags: sql, progress-db

Edit with more info:
Here is the basic Idea:

```
Select 
    ID,
    Site,
    Pay,
    Code
FROM STAFF
    WHERE CASE
    When 1/1/2013 < CURDATE() < 3/1/2013 then Staff."Code" in (1,2,3)
    When 3/1/2013 < CURDATE() < 5/1/2012 then Staff."Code" in (2,3,4)
    END
```

I almost never user Progress DB so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You,

Comment: You'll have to give a more complete example.  It's hard to figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
WHERE
    (CURDATE() BETWEEN 1/1/2013 AND 3/1/2013 AND Staff."Code" IN (1,2,3)) OR
    (CURDATE() BETWEEN 3/1/2013 AND 5/1/2013 AND Staff."Code" IN (2,3,4))
```

Comment: I added a bit to my example, your answer looks like it might work though